# Recursividad, Suma de digitos pares

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, recursión, vb

```
#En este codigo deberia de sumar recursivamente los digitos pares, soy aprendiz en python,
#se que es algo muy basico pero por favor si me pudieran colaborar para saber en que fallo
#Muchas gracias de antemano
def sumdig(num,suma):
    if num<0:
        print("La suma de los digitos pares es: ", suma)

    else:
        if num%2==0:
            a=num%10
            num=num/10
            return sumdig(num, suma+a)
```

Hasta aqui tengo pensado de lo que se hizo es analizar si el num es par y siendo asi
lo suma a la variable suma de la funcion
else:
num=num/10
return sumdig(num,suma)

```
num=int(input("Deme un numero: "))
suma=0
print(sumdig(num,suma))
```

Comment: Buen día, para entender mejor tu pregunta, ¿Lo que deseas es separar un número en dígitos y sumar únicamente los dígitos que sean par? Es decir, si ingresas 123456, ¿El resultado sería 12?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Buen dia, asi es: lo que intento es sumar los digitos pares como mencionas

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

hay varias formas, pero lo haré respetando lo mayor posible tu código:

```
def sumdig(num,suma):
    if num<=0:
        print("La suma de los digitos pares es: ", suma)
    else:
        ultimo= num%10
```

es necesario obtener cada uno de los últimos valores del número

```
        if ultimo%2 == 0:
```

Ahora si, verificamos que sea divisible por dos y el resultado sea 0

```
            suma += ultimo
```

sumamos ese valor

```
        num=num//10
```

Dividimos el numero para que sea eliminado el que usamos

```
sumdig(num, suma)
```

la recursión la realizo fuera antes del return y después retorno la suma

```
return suma


num=int(input("Deme un numero: "))
suma = 0
sumdig(num, suma)
```

es todo casi igual solo que llamo a la función sin el print

la función completa:

```
def sumdig(num,suma):
    if num<=0:
        print("La suma de los digitos pares es: ", suma)
    else:
        ultimo= num%10
        if ultimo%2 == 0:
            suma += ultimo
        num=num//10
        sumdig(num, suma)
    return suma


num=int(input("Deme un numero: "))
suma = 0
sumdig(num, suma)
```

y esto retorna:

```
Deme un numero: 123456
La suma de los digitos pares es:  12
```

Espero que si no es lo que buscas por lo menos te oriente.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra opción un poco más compacta que también acepta números negativos

```
def sumDigits(no):
    # Tomamos el valor absoluto del número
    no = abs(no)
    # Si el número introducido en la función es 0 terminar la recursividad, es decir, cuando ya se hayan evaluado todos los dígitos
    if no == 0:
        return 0
    # Si el número es par, tomar el último dígito y llamar la función con el número dividido entre 10
    # Es decir, si el número original era 126 se toma el último dígito 6 y se divide entre 10, nos devolvería 12
    # Y se vuelve a llamar la función pero ahora con 12
    if no % 2 == 0:
        return (no % 10) + sumDigits((no // 10))
    # Si el número es impar, llamar a la función con el siguiente dígito
    else:
        return sumDigits((no // 10))

print(sumDigits(int(input('Introduce un número: '))))
```

Prueba:

```
[In]: Introduce un número:  -2222221545788
[Out]: 32

[In]: Introduce un número:  123456789456123
[Out]: 32

[In]: Introduce un número:  123456
[Out]: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar todos los dígitos del número introducido a una lista y, mediante [slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings_slicing.asp), sumar solo los dígitos en posiciones pares:

```
def sumdig(num):
    suma =sum([int(numero) for numero in list(num)[1::2]])
    print("La suma de los digitos pares del número",num,"es:", suma)
    

num=input("Deme un numero: ")

sumdig(num)

Deme un numero: 123456
La suma de los digitos pares del número 123456 es: 12

Deme un numero: 123
La suma de los digitos pares del número 8974323 es: 2

Deme un numero: 8974323
La suma de los digitos pares del número 8974323 es: 15
```

La función coge el número introducido como texto, lo separa en dígitos individuales, luego por slicing se queda solo con los dígitos en posición par y posteriormente mediante [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) (un bucle) lo convierte todo a números y hace la suma.

Por el contrario, si lo que quieres es, dado un número, sumar aquellos dígitos que sean pares, independientemente de su posición, la idea es la misma pero con 1 paso adicional:

```
def sumdig(num):
    numeros =[int(numero) for numero in list(num)]
    suma=sum([numero for numero in numeros if (numero%2)==0])
    print("La suma de los digitos pares del número",num,"es:", suma)
    

num=input("Deme un numero: ")

sumdig(num)

Deme un numero: 12333334
La suma de los digitos pares del número 12333334 es: 6

Deme un numero: 1234
La suma de los digitos pares del número 1234 es: 6
```

Se crea una lista de números mediante list comprehension y luego se crea una nueva lista de la misma manera, pero solo con los números que sean pares, y se hace la suma final.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato gracias por tu comentario. Si leíste la respuesta entera, verás que el segundo código hace exactamente lo que dices, sumar aquellos dígitos que sean un número par, independientemente de su posición